# Position sizeToFit() - bottom right

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, positioning

I want to place an UIButton to the right side of my screen with a margin.
The buttonWidth is the by sizeToFit()

How can I make it stick to the right with a margin?

e.g.:

**Create & add the button**

```
let btn = UIButton()
btn.setTitle("hello", forState: .Normal)
btn.sizeToFit()
self.addSubview(btn)
```

**My unsuccess attempt to position it at the right upper corner (I also need a margin)**

```
btn.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
```

Comment: You need to access the btn.frame or btn.center property to set the buttons position. If you would prefer to use constraints then you should look at a constraints based approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button frame likes this way also:

```
self.btnOutlet.frame =CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-(self.btnOutlet.frame.size.width+RightMarginValue), 15, self.btnOutlet.frame.size.width , self.btnOutlet.frame.size.height);

self.view addSubview(btnOutlet);
```

Comment: I was hoping there is any solution where I can set the maxX-Value or something similar

Comment: you can set your margin value in RightMarginValue value.

Comment: I know... It is working. The point is that I was hoping there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @mika : This is the best way to do it.    +1 for bhadresh for a dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually position the button using its `frame.origin` or `center`, or use `AutoLayout`. Autoresizing masks are used when there's a change in the superview's layout.